# doctrine2 change referencedColumnName symfony2

Tags: doctrine-orm

how to change in a ManyToOne relation entity, the column name where the entity A look for the ID in the entity B ?

```
Table A
--------
id
title


Table B
---------
id
description
code_article
```

I want to look for id table A = code_article table B

How to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `@JoinColumn` annotation.

```
/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="TableA")
 * @JoinColumn(name="code_article", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $article;
```